# Difference between status codes and error codes

Tags: java, servlets, http-status-codes

folks,

How can I differentiate between error codes and status codes in case of Servlet response? Is it right to say that there is some status codes in HttpServletResponse class which show errors. Or I've to use more definite way to differentiate between them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[HTTP status codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) are considered "client errors" if they are in the 400-499 range and "server errors" if they're above 500.

They're also defined as constants [in the HttpServletResponse](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html) class.